# Does a convex solid with no stable equilibrium points exist?

Tags: geometry, classical-mechanics

I believe I can prove that such a solid doesn't exist, because if it did it leads to perpetual, motion as the solid could not remain still in any position on a horizontal surface once it is set in motion, and that is against the first and second law of thermodinamics.
My question is if there is a mathematical proof without resorting to physics

Comment: Such an mathematical object still wouldn't have the capacity to do infinite work, so I don't see how it breaks any law.

Comment: Take a look at this: https://www.nature.com/articles/d41586-023-02538-0

Comment: Brian, do you mean that it could still exist and stop moving at some point even not having a stable equilibrium point, therefore my statement is not a proof?

Comment: It seems the minimum, in 3D, is one stable equilibrium point (with the possible exception of the sphere, I assume). See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mechanical_equilibrium and https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6mb%C3%B6c. Note also that the sphere has no stable equilibrium point, depending how "stable equilibrium" is defined.

Comment: No, what I'm saying is that no law of thermodynamics says that an object in motion must eventually stop.  As best I can tell, you seem to be mixing up an object's capacity to do work with its capacity to move.

Comment: There is indeed a convex solid which if set in motion on a horizontal surface will - in the absence of frictional forces - never stop moving. There weird solid is called a "sphere".

Comment: Paul, a sphere is always in stable equilibrium (CG) on a horizontal surface, because a vertical line from the CG will always pass through the rest point no matter how much it is displaced from any position. An example of unstable equilibrium is a cone resting on its vertix. An infinitesimal displacement from its resting position will set it in motion until it finds rest on its side. The CG lies on one point in the axis so the vertical througn the CG will always pass through one of the resting points when moved along its side, so it is in stable equilibrium

Comment: An object in unstable equilibrium starts its motion by converting its own potential energy into kinetic energy. If it doesn't have a point of stable equilibrium (I claim) it will continue doing this for ever regrdless of friction, but perpetual motion is impossible, so what is the proof that an object without stable equilibrium points does not exist?